# Compared to what do we calculate Electric Potential? (Highschool Level)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, coulombs-law

Hey I have a question about electric potential and its relation to objects.

As I understand it, Electric potential is a property of an object that depends on its surroundings and other objects around it unlike mass, for example, which does not depend on stuff around it. The mass of a football on earth or on the moon or in an electromagnetic field is the same regardless of its surroundings.

Now I understand what electric potential in theory is. It represents the electric potential energy per coulomb of charge and is equal to Ep/q or k q/r (with this equation we see it is defined with charge **and distance**) . What I do not understand however, is how it's used. When you say something has some amount of electric potential, that means nothing because to me because you haven't stated the charged particle we are comparing it to.

The electric potential of a steel ball could be zero if there was not charged particle around it or it could be large if there was a highly charge particle close to it. Electric potential is the result of a relationship between more than one charged particle. Let's take a 1.5V battery for example. 1.5 volts tells us that the voltage or difference in electric potential between the positive and negative part of the battery is 1.5 volts. **In comparison to what** is the electric potential of the positive and negative sides of the battery calculated?

Comment: Compared to each other. There is always an issue with defining a "ground" potential, and if you get into complex enough electronics you will find multiple "ground" in many devices that may not be 0V relative to each other...

Comment: If we have a 1.5 V battery that means that the voltage or difference in electric potentials is 1.5V. This means that one side could be 900V and the other 901.5V (example numbers). Compared to what is one side 900V and the other 901.5? Can you elaborate?

Comment: If I attach the 1.5V battery in series with a 900V battery, and declare the (-) terminal of the 900V battery to be ground, than indeed the potentials are 900V and 901.5V on the terminals of the 1.5V battery, measured relative to the ground I defined. Or, declare the (-) terminal of the 1.5V battery to be ground, and the potentials at the terminals of the 900V battery are 0 and -900V.

Comment: So if I said this steel ball has 10V of electric potential. Compared to what charged particle does it have that potential? Also, do you know of any sources that I could check out. Surely I’m not the only person to ask this question, and i still don’t see the flaw in my logic.

Comment: It has 10V _relative_ to something.

Comment: Relative to what is my question. If i take this steel ball home will it all of a sudden have less electric potential because it is further away from the charge? Same with a battery, will it lose electric potential if i take it home? (obviously not)

Comment: The potential difference will not change, but the electric field will.

Comment: In case of a battery it's the potential of one electrode relative to the other. The potential against infinity (the physicist's version of "ground") can be anything, just as you said. This is no different from a mechanical potential energy. We can put our spring/ball experiment on sea-level or on top of a high mountain. In one case the potential energy of the ball relative to sea-level is small, in the other case it's high. The ball will still oscillate the same when we pull on the spring. Potentials have this property: we can add an arbitrary constant number and the physics stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Electric potential is a property of an object

I consider it a property of a system.  The potential energy a book has while sitting on a shelf is not inherent in the book.  It's due to the interaction of the book and other masses nearby (like the earth) and their relationship.

> ...unlike mass, for example, which does not depend on stuff around it.

The charge of an object and the mass of an object do not depend on stuff around them.

But the gravitational *potential* of an object does depend on the gravitational field nearby (which is itself due to the "stuff" near the object).  Similarly, the electric potential of a charge depends on the electric field nearby (which is due in part to the charges nearby).

> When you say something has some amount of electric potential, that means nothing because to me because you haven't stated the charged particle we are comparing it to.

We always have to have a reference location, but sometimes that location is implied.

> Let's take a 1.5V battery for example. 1.5 volts tells us that the voltage or difference in electric potential between the positive and negative part of the battery is 1.5 volts.

That is exactly correct.  The positive side is 1.5V greater than the negative side.

> In comparison to what is the electric potential of the positive and negative sides of the battery calculated?

In comparison to each other.  If we can move a charge from the negative terminal to the positive terminal, we have increased its potential by 1.5V.  For some amount of charge, we know the energy that would be required (or released) by following that path.

When we consider a book on a shelf, we don't normally say the book has some exact amount of absolute gravitational potential energy.  Instead we say it has some amount relative to a reference location.  A book on a shelf 1m above a desk would release $mg(1\rm{m})\space  \rm{J}$ of energy by falling to the desk.

A charge at the positive terminal would release $Q(1.5\rm{V}) \space \rm{J}$ of energy by moving to the negative terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, electric potential is always relative to something. A common implicit assumption in textbooks is that the object whose potential is in question is enclosed in a conductive box that's very large compared to the size of the object. The potential of the box is taken to be zero. If the box is large enough, its precise dimensions have a negligible effect on the result, so you might, for simplicity, consider it infinitely large.